# how to iterate all days in last 30 days using Arraylist in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to get all days between today date to past 30 date. and i want to set this days to arraylist .

I get past 30 days using Calendar in java now I want to get all dates and set them to the ArrayList

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        Date toDate = cal.getTime();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -30);
        Date fromDate = cal.getTime();
```

help me for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
today.minusDays( 30 ).datesUntil( today ).toList()
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The `Calendar` class is not a fit for date-only values.

Furthermore that class is terribly flawed in design, and is now obsolete having been supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## `java.time.LocalDate`

For date-only values, use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html). To get a series of dates, call [`LocalDate.html#datesUntil`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#datesUntil(java.time.LocalDate)) to get a stream.

Get today’s date.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

Go back 30 days.

```
LocalDate thirtyDaysAgo = today.minusDays( 30 ) ;
```

Get a [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) of dates.

```
Stream< LocalDate > datesStream = thirtyDaysAgo.datesUntil( today ) ;
```

Make a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) of the objects from that stream.

```
List< LocalDate > dates = datesStream.toList() ;
```

We could combine those lines.

```
List< LocalDate > dates = today.minusDays( 30 ).datesUntil( today ).toList() ;
```